# Dynamically add elements to 2-D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to know how to create an array, and add elements to it with a nested for-loop. How do I declare the array?
I want the finished array to look like this:

```
var array2d = {
[0, 1, 2, 3],
[0, 1, 2, 3],
[0, 1, 2, 3],
[0, 1, 2, 3],
};
```

I don't want to make the inner arrays formatted as objects. I want a simple array which I can access like this:

```
var element = array2d[2][1]; //returns '1'
```

Comment: Replace the {}'s with []'s.

Comment: You declare that array like any other array: `var array2d = [];`

Answer (score 1):

What John Hartsock probably meant (in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712732/588079)) was:

```
var my2DArray = [], i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  my2DArray.push([]);
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    my2DArray[i].push("Array Position " + i + ", " + j);
  }
}

alert(my2DArray[0][0]); //will alert "Array Postion 0, 0"
alert(my2DArray[1][4]); //will alert "Array Postion 1, 4"
```

Working [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MpR79/).

*OR* using a *temporary reference* to each new 'sub-array' (can be faster):

```
var my2DArray = [], i, j, tempRef;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  tempRef = my2DArray[i] = [];
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    tempRef.push("Array Position " + i + ", " + j);
  } 
}

alert(my2DArray[0][0]); //will alert "Array Postion 0, 0"
alert(my2DArray[1][4]); //will alert "Array Postion 1, 4"
```

Working [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MpR79/2/).

**Explanation:**

One normally uses `var arr=[];` to create an array and `arr.push(/*content*/);` to add a new array-item to the end of the array (so it is essentially the same as `arr[arr.length]=/*content*/;`).

Thus, if you have an array (`my2DArray`), then you add *new* arrays (since arrays are passed by reference, not copied) to your main/root array: `my2DArray.push([]);` to make `my2DArray[my2DArray.length]` reference this new array (and once this array exists, you can do stuff with it: `my2DArray[index][sub_index]`).

So, say you have just one loop, then you could also add a complete new array with a single push: `my2DArray.push([0,1,2,3]);`

Put differently, (using what is explained above,) this single line will create *exactly* the 2d array you gave as example in your question:

```
for(var array2d=[], i=0; i<4; array2d[i++]=[0, 1, 2, 3]);
alert(  array2d[2][1]  );  //returns '1'
```

[jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MpR79/1/).

By the way, technically there aren't even arrays in javascript, just fancy objects with some special features (**excellent explanation here**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891043/588079)

Comment: While the last comment about arrays being "fancy objects" is relevant, it should still be pointed out that some distinction is made due to the global `Array` constructor existing as a separate entity from `Object`.

Comment: wtf ?!? adding url's changes the last array-index of the last line of each code-block

Comment: @ajp15243: About your suggested edit: I used `/*content*/` so I wouldn't have to explain [objects, wrappers, values, primitives etc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16115543/588079). Also 'JavaScript' (note casing) refers to an engine implementation, so I specifically use 'javascript' (when I mean ES). As to your comment, you are right, that's why I pointed to an excellent answer on SO. But *thank you* for caring!

Comment: Fair enough, and you're welcome!